# Why doesn't this TamperMonkey script alert, log or break?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Why doesn't this minimal script for Vitacost.com show the alert, hit the breakpoint or log?  I'm using Chrome on Win 7.

```
// ==UserScript==
//
// @name         VitaCost_Test
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.5
// @description  Why don't TamperMonkey scripts run on VitaCost.com???
// @match        *://*.vitacost.com/*
// @match        *://vitacost.com/*
// @match        *://vitacost.com
// @match        https://www.vitacost.com/
// @match        https://www.vitacost.com
// @grant         none
//
// @filename     C:\Users\Public\Documents\Source\js\Grease-Tamper Monkey\VitaCost_Test.js
// ==/UserScript==

debugger;
alert("VitaCost_test");
console.log("VitaCost_test");

(function() {
    'use strict';
debugger;
alert("VitaCost_test function");
console.log("VitaCost_test function");
});
```

Comment: Works here. The script is probably disabled your TM's dashboard.

Comment: Are you perhaps visiting the root of the site, with just `.com` with no slash? Your URL match looks like it requires the `/` at the end.

Comment: @DBS - Added more "@match" tags.  Still no luck.

Comment: @DBS: Can you even visit a site without the trailing slash on the *domain*? Firefox doesn't allow it AFAICT, I didn't think any browser did that.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Looks enabled unless I'm not reading it right: https://imgur.com/dTjQhV8

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the original code, it works, no need to change anything. Since the script is indeed enabled, the problem might be a bug in Tampermonkey. Open `chrome://policy` and see if that URL is there. If not, try reproducing in a new empty browser profile.